# both max_iter_predict=1 and max_iter_predict=10 in GaussianProcessClassifier give the same results

Tags: scikit-learn, hyperparameters

What is **max_iter_predict** responsible for? When I try different values (from 1 to 50), the result still doesn't change.

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier.html#sklearn.gaussian_process.GaussianProcessClassifier):

> max_iter_predict : int, optional (default: 100)
>
> The maximum number of iterations in Newton’s method for approximating
>   the posterior during predict. Smaller values will reduce computation
>   time at the cost of worse results

**Since the results do not change in your case, I would conclude that even using `max_iter_predict=1` the `Newton’s method for approximating the posterior during predict`is estimated sufficiently.**